# AbstractMethodError for SQLXML

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, jdbc, sqlxml

I need to **add xml data** in sql server 2008 and i'm using jre 6  as runtime in eclipse IDE.

When i run my programs, i get this error:

> " java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.ConnectionJDBC3.createSQLXML()Ljava/sql/SQLXML;"

for connection i'm using ojdbc14.jar.

What is the problem here ?

Answer (score 0):

SQLXML is a JDBC 4 feature not supported in JDBC 3.

JTDS is a JDBC 3 driver.

http://sourceforge.net/p/jtds/feature-requests/65/

They have removed the AbstractMethodErrors during their build process, but from what I can tell they have not done a release since they fixed that bug, so the current release still has the problem. Not sure if the method would then just be a NOOP or throw an UnsupportedOperationException. Either way it would not help you since the result would still be a dead end (i.e., no desired functionality).

I am still working on getting it working, but apparently if you want to save XML to SQL Server as an XML type, then you have to use the MS JDBC driver.